# How to remove first segment or segments from PATH in shell script

Tags: bash, conda

I wanted to remove a CUDA directory from PATH by a .sh script when deactivate a conda virtual environment like described in this [link](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/multiple-version-of-cuda-libraries-on-the-same-machine-b9502d50ae77). 
The env variables are showed by `echo $PATH`.

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/home/dude/anaconda/envs/my_v_env/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
```

So I create a .sh file in /home/dude/anaconda/envs/my_v_env/etc/conda/deactivate.d/.

My followed **.sh script changes nothing but it DOES in terminal**(this script will be automatically executed when I do `conda deactivate`):

```
export PATH=$(echo ${PATH} | sed -r 's|/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin||')
```

I want only after deactivating the venv:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
```

`/home/dude/anaconda/envs/my_v_env/bin` is deleted automatically but I still have the segment of `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:` in the PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this removes the first two entries on the path using stream manipulation:

```
num_entries_to_remove=2
export PATH=`echo $PATH | sed 's/\:/\n/g' | tail -n+$(expr $num_entries_to_remove + 1) | tr '\n' ':'`
```